# Case-insensitive search in Pig Latin

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, bigdata

Beginner in Pig Latin here.
I am trying to count the occurrences of multiple strings in an input file.

Now the search has to be case-insensitive. I know there is a `LOWER` built-in function in pig but how do I use it ?

For example (Input file):

```
28-Oct-13,7:00PM,Viraj,New to hadoop ! Eager to learn.
31-Dec-14,3:00PM,‏Vanguard,Designers, Developers, Doers, don't miss this upcoming San Francisco Hadoop
```

I need the count of strings like `hadoop, dec, learn, python`

```
hadoop 2
dec 1
learn 1
python 0
```

How do I do this search in pig Latin ?

Thank you.

Comment: I have solved similar kind of question to another guy but its looks like it didn't work well for him, so can you try the below solution and let me know if this works for you?. The below solution working fine for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try this?

**input**

```
28-Oct-13,7:00PM,Viraj,New to hadoop ! Eager to learn.
31-Dec-14,3:00PM,?Vanguard,Designers, Developers, Doers, don't miss this upcoming San Francisco Hadoop
```

**PigScript:**

```
A = LOAD 'input' AS (line:chararray);
B = FOREACH A GENERATE  FLATTEN(TOKENIZE(LOWER(line))) as word;
C = FOREACH B GENERATE ((word matches '.*hadoop.*'? 1:0)) as t1,((word matches '.*dec.*'?1:0)) as t2,((word matches '.*learn.*'?1:0)) as t3,((word matches '.*python.*'?1:0)) as t4;
D = GROUP C ALL;
E  = FOREACH D GENERATE FLATTEN(TOBAG(CONCAT('hadoop',' ',(chararray)SUM(C.t1)),CONCAT('dec',' ',(chararray)SUM(C.t2)),CONCAT('learn',' ',(chararray)SUM(C.t3)),CONCAT('python',' ',(chararray)SUM(C.t4))));
DUMP E;
```

**Output:**

```
(hadoop 2)
(dec 1)
(learn 1)
(python 0)
```

Comment: The above works fine. Just that the CONCAT function takes in 2 parameters so had to change it a bit.  How about if we want to search for strings that are like this "Hadoop", "DEC" etc ? So we need to convert them to lowercase and do it ?

Comment: I already converted the entire strings to lower case  in the script 'LOWER(line)' . Do you want separate total count for  hadoop and  Hadoop ?

Comment: No. I mean can we convert the search string to LOWER too ?

Comment: In this script your search string should be only lower case, reason is we converted all the string to lower in the step2  (relation B), so you need to search only using lower case. In the step3 (relation C) you cannot convert search string to lower because this is regex matching string LOWER function will not. If i am not answered your question pls give me some examples

Comment: Yes. You answered correctly but is there any other method in which we can convert string to LOWER and then search ?

Comment: One option could be you can make the search string as case insensitive in regex. ((word matches '(?i).*hadoop.*'? 1:0))